# Flutter No Method `get` in DocumentSnapshot

Tags: mysql, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Despite the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#get), Flutter is giving me the error:

`The method 'get' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentSnapshot'.`

Here is my code:

```dart
  Future<Object> getFromDocumentSnapshot(String email, String field) async {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(email)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      return ds.get(field);
    });
  }
```

Not sure about this one. Any obvious issues? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The link that you referenced is for javascript and not flutter which uses dart programming language. If you want to get a document in flutter, then you have to do the following:

```
Firestore.instance
        .collection('talks')
        .document('document-name')
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      // use ds as a snapshot
    });
```

You need to use the plugin `cloud_firestore`:

https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

As you can see the `DocumentSnapshot` does not contain method `get()`:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_snapshot.dart

Answer (score 0):

To access the data in the [`DocumentSnapshot` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html), use its `data` property. For example:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .document(email)
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
  return ds.data[field];
});
```